# Promise.all() does not give results separetely

Tags: reactjs, api, promise.all

I'm working on a React project where I have to make multiple API calls. So, the way I have been doing is using Promise.all(), but it returns all the results at the same time which sometimes too slow and bad for users' experience. I wonder if there is anyway that I can fetch all the APIs at the same time but still give the results separately so that I can display them in "first fetched first show" order?

Comment: Yea, each promise you pass to promise.all can have it's own resolve callbacks..

Comment: do you know how I could achieve that? I have been doing like: 
```
async function fetchData (){
   const res = await Promise.all()
   console.log(res)
}
``